# Security rules "get()" not working on app

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

*Performing the `get()` function in security rules is not working.*

It returns permission denied on the client, but passes in simulation.

[image]

The config/permissions layout is an array structure:

config/permissions-->

---------------------------> CollectionName1 :

----------------------------------------------------> 0 : UID1

----------------------------------------------------> 1 : UID2

---------------------------> CollectionName2 :

----------------------------------------------------> 0 : UID3

----------------------------------------------------> 1 : UID4

I also tried to use single key/value fields in the config/permissions as so

config/permissions-->

---------------------------> CollectionName1 : UID1

---------------------------> CollectionName2 : UID3

with the rule

`allow read: if request.auth.uid == get(/config/permissions).data[c]` and this passed simulation and failed on the app. If I hardcode the UID instead of `request.auth.uid` it gives the same result.

UID is definitely correct on the app. This was tested by using the following rule, where it passed in simulation AND the app.

`allow read: if request.auth.uid == 'USER_ID_HERE'`

and by comparing the logcat output of the UID to the one above.

Please help. This is the Nth day of trying to find a suitable way to structure and query Firestore. I'm certain this is an issue with either the `get()` call or the way I am writing the call.

Android Code:

```
 FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
            .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
            .build();
    db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

    Log.d("UID", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection(collection).document("X153@111");
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    Log.d("FIREBASE", "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                } else {
                    Log.d("FIREBASE", "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("FIREBASE", "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i think that the problem may be in `.data[c]`

Comment: @V.Kalyuzhnyu Can you elaborate?

Comment: You're working on andorid 7?

Comment: Min 19 (Android 4.4) and target 27 (Android 8.1)

Comment: I have this same problem. It works in production environment, but not in dev. Passes simulator on both. No idea why the dev environment won't work even when passing the simulator...